# ValueError Feeding Data to KerasRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I'm trying to use Keras (version 2.0.6) and SKLearn (version 0.18.1) with Python 2.7 to do some basic machine learning.

I have my `X` input with 2,208 rows and 51,786 columns and am setting up my basic neural network as follows:

```
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=51786, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=2)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=100)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold)
```

Unfortunately, I get a `ValueError` as follows:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1766, 10) for Tensor u'dense_45_input:0', which has shape '(?, 51786)'
```

That shape, `(1766, 10)`, is the original shape used in the tutorial I'm borrowing code from.  However, I can't seem to find where else to change this shape (aside from `input_dim`)...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit: Running the below strangely seems to run:

```
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=2)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=100)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv=kfold)
print("Standardized: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Comment: can you upload the x and y data?

Comment: What is the dimensionality of your features? 51786 sounds quite odd.